# How to fix the "no serial profile" or gatt status 133 problem with esp32 BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am using esp32 dev kit with wi-fi and bluetooth features in this project with MAX30102 pulseoximetry sensor and electrical stimulation electrode. I am using bluetooth to connect esp32 to phone and read the output via esp32 bluetooth terminal which I downloaded from Google Play.

Here is the code on esp32:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>
#include "MAX30102_PulseOximeter.h"
#define BUTTON_PIN 2
#define SERVICE_UUID "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define STEP_DATA_CHAR_UUID "beefcafe-36e1-4688-b7f5-00000000000b"
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000
BLECharacteristic *pStepDataCharacteristic;

float BPM, SpO2;
const int shocker = 2;
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
void onBeatDetected()
{
  Serial.println("Beat Detected!");
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(19, OUTPUT);
 if (!pox.begin()) {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    for (;;);
  } else {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
  }
  pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30102_LED_CURR_7_6MA);

  BLEDevice::init("Step-Sense");
  
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  // Create step data characteristic
  pStepDataCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      STEP_DATA_CHAR_UUID,
      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
  pStepDataCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  // Start BLE server and advertising
  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("BLE device is ready to be connected");


  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);


}

void loop() {
  pox.update();
  BPM = pox.getHeartRate();
  SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();
  analogWrite(shocker, 30);
  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS)
  {
    
    Serial.print("BPM: ");
    Serial.println(BPM);
    Serial.print("SpO2: ");
    Serial.print(SpO2);
    Serial.println("%");
    Serial.println("*");
    Serial.println();
    tsLastReport = millis();
  }
  int result = (int)BPM;
  pStepDataCharacteristic->setValue(result);
  pStepDataCharacteristic->notify();

}
```

When I am trying to connect to the phone, esp32 can be seen in Bluetooth tab in phone and in bluetooth terminal app. But when I am trying to connect to it to see the terminal, either "no serial profile found" or "gatt status 133" errors occur.

I tried rebooting and using another esp, didn't work
I am expecting it to connect to the app and to see the BPM values in terminal.

Comment: Where did you get the UUID from? Is it the one that esp32 bluetooth terminal expects? Please use a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see if you can find the service and read your values